# Timestamp in node js different from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In database time-stamp is saved as **2015-12-05 10:53:12** but when I fetch record using mysql query it return this time-stamp like **2015-12-05T10:53:12.000Z**.
Why? any issue?? please help.

Comment: They are the same thing. The difference is how they represented. Put them in `new Date()` and play with it. The details are in JavaScript docs.

Comment: @iam - for your reference timestamp format is **YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]** when you fetch from database using mysql command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your database the timestamp is saved in binary numerical format. "2015-12-05 10:53:12" & "2015-12-05T10:53:12.000Z" are string representation of that value that you see in some application.

It's the same value and there's no issue to solve here.

Comment: but I want to convert it into look like Dec 16, 2015. Is it possible??

Comment: From within NodeJS? lookup javascript date to string on Google or something

Comment: dateFormat(result[i]['created'], "mmmm d, yyyy") returning  "December 5, 2015".  how to get "Dec 5, 2015"?

Answer (score 1):

To convert your Date-Object (which is represented as ISOString with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") you have to parse it after reading from the db.

In JavaScript you can do that by simply passing the string in the constructor, e.g. **var myDate = new Date("2015-12-05T10:53:12.000Z")**

With a custom format you could do it like this for example:

var dateString = "2015-12-05 10:53:12";
var date = Date.parse(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

In order to represent it as "Dec 16, 2015" you have to parse it afterwards:

There are some good libraries for doing this (e.g. [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) or with [angularjs - date filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date))

Without that you have do manually do it somehow like this (where you pass your date object created before):

```
  function parseDate(date) {
    var months = ['JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN',
      'JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC'];
    return months[date.getMonth()]+" "+("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2)+", "+date.getUTCFullYear();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's DATE_FORMAT, eg.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%W %M %Y'); -> 'Sunday October 2009'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format